# Tracing the email's MAC address

Tags: email, mac-address, tracking

Can someone trace the MAC address of an email to the point of origin if the email address has been deleted? I received an email from an unknown sender regarding an issue at my work, and when I tried to reply to it, I got a "message send: failure" email from my email provider. This tells me that whoever sent me this message deleted the email account to prevent being discovered. The message contained some statements to my friend from some of my co-workers. I had never seen them until I got this email. Is there a way to find out where it came from?

I have already gone through the answers given about the same topic. But it's 2023, so probably there would be some way.

Comment: Do you have the MAC address in the email? Why are you concluding that  "message send: failure" means that the email address was "deleted"? I think you are making a lot of very specific assumptions, which will make this question very difficult to answer.

Comment: It's probably just a spoofed e-mail sender header...

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: it is not possible what you want.

> Can someone trace the MAC address of an email ...

An email does not have a MAC address in the first place. If you mean the MAC address of the computer from which the mail was originally sent - this cannot be tracked and its usually also irrelevant since a MAC address is a property of a network card only visible and relevant in the local network, i.e. not exposed to the internet at all. Apart from that knowing the MAC has a questionable value, since today it will be often changed from time to time by software in order to not prevent broad tracking of a user between different networks (like open WiFi hotspots).

> This tells me that whoever sent me this message deleted the email account to prevent being discovered. ..

The conclusion that the address must have been deleted is wrong. Reply mails might also be rejected due to the wrong recipient if the `Reply-To` of the original mail was set to an account which does not exist. If such `Reply-To` exists it will be used instead of `From` as the recipient when replying to a mail. It can be set by the sender of the original mail to anything, there will be no verification if this exists. Even if there was no `Reply-To` the address given as `From` can still be spoofed. While SPF, DKIM and DMARC provide some protection here they are a) not universally deployed and enforced and b) work only at the level of the domain. The latter means that spoofing of an email within the same domain will still not be detected by these mechanism.